# Show @odata.id in OData response C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

We are using the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API for Odata v4.0 package for constructing an OData service based on the DynamicEdmModelCreation project of ODataSamples-master. We want that our own resources response with the **@odata.id** and the **@odata.editLink** annotations like this one(currently our responses only comes with the @odata.context annotation):

`{
 "@odata.context":  "http://services.odata.org/V4/.../TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People",
 "@odata.nextLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/.../TripPinServiceRW/People?%24skiptoken=8",
 "value": [
 {
 "@odata.id": "http://services.odata.org/V4/.../TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')",
"@odata.etag": "W/\"08D316E3F5DF36AF\"",
"@odata.editLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/.../People('russellwhyte')",
...
}`

This example comes from the odata official page http://www.odata.org/ and can be requested with this url

http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(l4xyndr2pr1j1usz3cetf5zp))/TripPinServiceRW/People

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client, set the `Accept` request header to `application/json;odata.metadata=full`.